# Error: Invariant Violation: Grid.render()

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use React-bootstrap on my page, but i'm getting an error on my first component. I've scaffolded a page with yeoman fluxible generator, and am trying to add react-bootstrap to it.

```
import {Grid} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Col} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Application extends React.Component {
render() {
    var Handler = this.props.currentRoute.get('handler');

    return (
        <div>
          <Grid>
            <Row>
                 <Col xs={12} md={8}>
                     <Nav selected={this.props.currentPageName} links={this.props.pages} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Handler />
                </Col>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But when I run it I get the error `Error: Invariant Violation: Grid.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Answer (score 0):

Fluxible generator uses react 0.13, which is not compatible with react-bootstrap. After upgrading react to 0.14.3 it works.